# Not equal to operator in Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am facing a strange problem. As per shopify documentation, != is not equal to. However when I use it, the IDE is not recognizing it. Below is two screenshots. In one when I replace != with == the variable following the == gets highlighted. When I replace it with != the variable is not getting highlighted and the logic is failing too. How do I correct it.

The line I am referring in each image is `if tag != 'sweets' or …`:

[image: With != operator]

[image: Second pic, replacing != with ==]

***Edited***

```html
{% if collection.all_tags.size > 0 %}
<div class="form-horizontal">
<label for="BrowseBy">{{ 'collections.sorting.city' | t }}</label>
{% comment %}Good for /collections/all collection and regular collections{% endcomment %}
{% if collection.handle %}
    {% capture collection_url %}/collections/{{ collection.handle }}{% unless collection.sort_by == blank %}?sort_by={{ collection.sort_by }}{% endunless %}{% endcapture %}
    {% comment %}Good for automatic type collections{% endcomment %}
{% elsif collection.current_type %}
    {% assign collection_url = collection.current_type | url_for_type | sort_by: collection.sort_by  %}
    {% comment %}Good for automatic vendor collections{% endcomment %}
{% elsif collection.current_vendor %}
    {% assign collection_url = collection.current_vendor | url_for_vendor | sort_by: collection.sort_by %}
{% endif %}
<select name="BrowseBy" id="BrowseBy" class="btn--tertiary">
    <option value="{{ collection_url }}">{{ 'collections.sorting.all_tags' | t }}</option>
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% if tag == 'jamshedpur' or tag == 'ranchi' %}
        {% capture new_url %}{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag | split: 'href="' | last | split: '"' | first }}{% endcapture %}
        <option{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected{% endif %} value="{{ new_url }}">{{ tag }}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<label for="BrowseBy">{{ 'collections.sorting.category' | t }}</label>
    <select name="BrowseBy" id="BrowseBy" class="btn--tertiary">
    <option value="{{ collection_url }}">{{ 'collections.sorting.all_tags' | t }}</option>
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
        {% if tag == 'sweets' or tag == 'cake' or tag == 'savories' %}
        {% capture new_url %}{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag | split: 'href="' | last | split: '"' | first }}{% endcapture %}
        <option{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected{% endif %} value="{{ new_url }}">{{ tag }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <label for="BrowseBy">{{ 'collections.sorting.shop' | t }}</label>
    <select name="BrowseBy" id="BrowseBy" class="btn--tertiary">
    <option value="{{ collection_url }}">{{ 'collections.sorting.all_tags' | t }}</option>
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
        {% if tag != 'sweets' or tag != 'cake' or tag != 'savories' or tag != 'jamshedpur' or tag != 'ranchi'  %}
        {% capture new_url %}{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag | split: 'href="' | last | split: '"' | first }}{% endcapture %}
        <option{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected{% endif %} value="{{ new_url }}">{{ tag }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
{% endif %}

<script>
    $(function() {
    $('#BrowseBy')
    .bind('change', function() {
    location.href = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @marcanuy i have pasted the complete code.

Comment: Use "and" instead of "or" in your condition. Just a simple logic flaw in your code.